# JDBC execute INSERT statement with a function

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-insert, callable-statement

How to use JDBC to execute an `INSERT` statement which has a user defined PL/SQL function in `VALUES` clause?

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (plsql_func_name('?'),?,?,?);
```

Should `prepareStatement()` or `callablestatement()` be used?

Comment: You should use `prepareStatement()` but you must not enclose the `?` in parentheses. So it should be `VALUES (plsql_func_name(?),?,?,?)` not `... plsql_func_name('?') ... `

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The apostrophes around the parameter are your undoing. Try it this way:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (plsql_func_name(?),?,?,?);
```

Remember that the apostrophes are handled by the prepared statement, as this is one of its main jobs (as it has to prevent potential SQL-injections as well).